# Chamar pagina xhtml pelo commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou implementando o componente toolbar do primefaces e dentro desse componente tem diversos commandButtons que preciso que ao clicar ele chame outra pagina xhtml do meu projeto. Como faz?
ex:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Cadastro de Cliente"
                icon="ui-icon-plus"  action="CadastroClientePrime.xhtml" />
```

Comment: tente usar outcome ao invés de action

Comment: Deste jeito não funcionou?

Comment: O comentário do @DiegoAugusto também é válido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns modos de navegação tais como dinâmicamente, estático e redirecionado.

para navegação estatica veja um exemplo simples:

```
<p:commandButton value="Sobre" action="sobre" />
```

lembrando que para minha página dei o nome de "sobre.xhtml".

Agora, veja um exemplo de navegação dinâmica, dessa forma é necessário um metodo

```
 <p:commandButton value="Sobre" action="#{ControlePrincipal.sobre()}" />
```

Metodo:

```
  public String sobre()
  {
    return "sobre";
  }
```